# How to change EditText border line color in program code?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Actually I have 2 questions.

1. How to change edittext border line color and size?
   Other answers like use shape.xml to describe the rect detail and set android:background of EditText as @drawable/shape does not work for me, because I need to change focus cursor color too.
   I try to use styles.xml and set colorAccent as the line color, and set EditText android:theme as this. It works for color, but I cannot figure out how to change line size in style.xml.
2. I want to change the color of EditText at running time, how to change the EditText line color and focus cursor color in program code?

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much!

I want to change the white line size as 1 dp.

Comment: The size of the line depends on the EditText Width.We cant change it dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean I can change the android:layout_width of EditText and the border line will get thinner? But I need to set the size as a fixed number such as 1dp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

For API level `21` or `>21`

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red));
editText.setBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
```

For API level `< 21`

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

`android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` will give you the cursor color same as text color of `EditText` which you have applied.

For border line :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#9ba3af"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Piyush, I think I solve the color problem now, do you know how to set the border line as 1dp for EditText?

Comment: Rectangle border line ? @shaopingwang

Comment: No, my EditText shapes like a line not a Rectangle, maybe I can add a picutre to help reviewers to understand my question.

Comment: @shaopingwang Don't need to add border. Its a background tint for Edittext. Still you want that kinda border then make background of edittext transparent and take one View with 1 dp height below edittext which will give you desire edittext.

Comment: I use your edited answer it can change the size of the border line but there is another question is the line is not below the hint message but cross across the hint message line. I set the android:bottom at padding label and it works.

Comment: Hi Piyush. Sorry to bother you again, I have a textView below my EditView, if I set the padding bottom and make the border line move down avoiding cross hint message, the gap between EditText and TextView will enlarge. Do you know why?

Comment: @shaopingwang Show me your xml file.

Comment: I can not upload my code in stackoverflow successfully, so I email the xml files to you at address  piyush.gupta569@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.AppColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

also 
`android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to @null should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Use this code in your java class.

Comment: Thank you so much Arpan! I try your advice, android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null will make the cursor thinner and its color has been changed too. SetColorFilter can also successfully change the border line color. I think I just need to solve the line size setting now  ：）